# Weird folder names in ~/Library/Preferences

Tags: macos, folders

These empty folders are in my Library > Preferences.  Have I been infected with malware?

[image]

I am running OS X 10.10, Yosemite, with the latest update on a Mac Mini.

Comment: Any contents in those folders?

Comment: As the patterns are similar, there may be something not translating unicode correctly. Is the OS in English?

Comment: This question was answered by Graham Miln.  But to answer the questions posed to me: The folders had not content, The OS was in English, and the folder names from the terminal is the same as what I posted above. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely your Mac is infected.

The odd folder names within `~/Library/Preferences` is likely due to a crashing Mac application or process. The crash may be happening within a preferences related section of the application and causing garbage values to be passed to the preferences.

### Safe to remove

Assuming a reasonable application is responsible for these files, you should always be able to delete contents from `~/Library/Preferences` without loosing critical information or work.

Delete the folders and check again after running a few of your applications. Do they return?

Comment: Restart to your `Recovery HD` open `Disk Utility` and check/repair your main volume (probably named `Macintosh HD`) before deleting anything. The phenomenon may also occur through meta data corruption.